# How to optimize this method in Java? I am getting time Limit Exceed

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have two Lists, one has the index of elements and the other has the stock prices. For each index I have to find the minimum and nearest stock price upwards or downwards in the stock array whichever is smaller than the stock price at the current index and nearest.
Here is my code. It is accurate but is too slow so gives a **Time Limit execution error**;

```
public static List<Integer> predictAnswer(List<Integer> stockData, List<Integer> queries) {
    List<Integer> resQuery = new ArrayList<>();

    /* to show -1 if there is no such stock price */
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        resQuery.add(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        /* the query index starts from 1 or supposes the first index is 1 */
        int index = (int) (queries.get(i) - 1);
        int value = stockData.get(index).intValue();

        int j = index + 1;
        int k = index - 1;

        while (j < stockData.size() - 1 || k > 1) {

            if (k < 1) {
                if (stockData.get(j).intValue() < value) {
                    resQuery.set(i, j + 1);
                    break;
                }
            } 

            else if (j > stockData.size() - 1) {
                if (stockData.get(k).intValue() < value) {
                    resQuery.set(i, k + 1);
                    break;
                }
            } 

            else if (stockData.get(k).intValue() < value) {
                resQuery.set(i, k + 1);
                break;
            } 

            else if (stockData.get(j).intValue() < value) {
                resQuery.set(i, j + 1);
                break;
            }

            j++;
            k--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Can you help me to refactor this code in order to improve the performances?**

Comment: You have a runaway indentation, kind of cumulative. Please fix.

Comment: TLE - Tab Limit Exceeded. `:)`

Comment: I'm not sure I get what the inputs are or what the output should be, but I believe the solution is to use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), keyed by stock price, and the [`lowerEntry(K key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerEntry-K-) and [`higherEntry(K key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherEntry-K-) methods to find nearest stock price below/above a given stock price.

Comment: This doesn't seem a question about programming, but a question about algorithmic. Maybe having the full problem statement could help. Usually when solving these algorithmic problems, you have to be optimal.. A simple iteration might not work, and some other techniques should be used: dynamic programming, a HashMap, Greedy Algorithms, etc.. If you don't know about them, you might find them interesting and you will learn a lot!

Comment: If you sort the list first, you can do it by binary search.

Comment: I would need the index of target element (element which is nearest and smaller than the this element at present index) sorting would destroy the given order .....

Comment: @Andreas TreeMap would need unique elements to be kept as key right? what if the values are repeated in the StockData list?

Comment: @theUturn That's what Map-Lists and Map-Sets are used for, e.g. `TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>`, an ordered tree keyed by stock price, with an ordered set of indexes. `entry = treeMap.lowerEntry(42)` will return the largest stock price less than 42, and `entry.getValue().lower(13)` will return the largest index lower than 13. Combined with `higher(13)`, you can very quickly find the *nearest* index with of the nearest lower stock price below 42. --- TreeMap and TreeSet are both _O(log n)_ performance, so your code will end up _O(n log n)_ instead of _O(n²)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your algorithm has `O(n^2)` time complexity.
There are two classical methods to solve such problems in `O(n)`. The first one using a stack and the second one using dynamic programming.

I suggest an example to explain what is not good in your algorithm.

Suppose you have `[1, 4, 3, 2]` as stock prices.

For the third element `3`, it will iterate over `4` and then `1` to find the nearest smaller downwards.

For the last element `2`, it will iterate over `3`, `4` and then `1` to find the nearest smaller downwards. So it does not take into account the work you have done before with  `3` (it ignores the fact that you don't have to iterate over `4` because it is greater than `3` so greater than `2`). If you have many consecutive `4`, it will iterate over all of them rather than jumping directly to `1`.

The purpose of the algorithm with dynamic programming is to take into account the work you have done before. It uses an array to store the *index* of nearest smaller downwards for each stock price.
With the example above, The final version of this array will be `[-1, 0, 0, 0]` (`1` does not have a nearest smaller downwards so we represent it by -1, the nearest smaller for the others is `1` which is in index 0).

To compute this array, you initialize it by `[-1, -1, -1, -1]`.
For example, when processing the last element you will have `[-1, 0, 0, -1]`. You compare it to `3` and find that `3` is greater so you jump directly to the nearest smaller of `3` which is in index `0`. You then compare your element to the element in index `0` (which is `1`). `1` is smaller so you find the nearest smaller...

And you can do the same thing for nearest smaller upwards.

Comment: Thanks, that was eye-opening explanation